# How I can use the Autoloading in PHP?

Tags: php, file, autoload, htdocs

hi i learn php now and I test the Autoloading but it don't work. I have two files: `start.php` and `myClass.php`. The files I have in the path `./xampp/htdocs` and I want If I start start.php use the Autoloading for include the `myClass.php` and this functions.

here my Code:

start.php

```
<?php
    function _autoload($classname){
        $filename = "./".$classname.".php";
        include_once($filename);
    }

    $obj = new myClass();
?>
```

myClass.php

```
<?php
    class myClass {

        public function _construct(){

            echo "Die Klasse wurde erfolgreich erzeugt";
        }
    }
?>
```

I get this error:

Fatal error: Class 'myClass' not found in D:\Webserver\xampp\htdocs\start.php on line 7

What I make wrong.

Comment: Do not create your own. Use created one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use `spl_autoload_register` — Register given function as `__autoload()` implementation

```
    function _autoload($class) {
            $filename = $classname.".php"; //assumed, your class file and other files are in same directory
            include_once($filename);
    }


    spl_autoload_register('_autoload');
```

Comment: `_construct()` should `__construct()`

Comment: Make sure the classname path is right in the auto load function

Answer (score 2):

It's `__autoload()`, not `_autoload()`. With two underlines in front.

The same goes for your `_construct()` function.

Note: The PHP manual recommends to use `spl_autoload_register()` instead of the `__autoload()`  function because it allows more flexibility. Also, the `__autoload()` function is expected to become deprecated in the future.